# How to delete a fake score in game center leaderboard?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, leaderboard

I have found a lot of sites saying that apple let developers delete a leaderBoard score. But I can't find this buttom anywhere.

ps: My app ins't posted at appStore yet.

Answer (score 1):

Following this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/TestingYourApp/TestingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726-CH25-SW2):

1. Go to the Game Center page of your app, as described in Navigating to Your App’s Game Center Page.
2. In the Leaderboards section, click Delete Test Data.
   A request to Apple is submitted to delete your test data. Requests are usually processed within one day and can’t be restored.

[image]

Comment: I was asking about a single leaderboard score. Sorry =/

Comment: @Sanf0rd try checking this guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Leaderboards/Leaderboards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726-CH2-SW72